# Center the <af:outputText> element in ADF template

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How can I center the  in adf template ?

Following is the code

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_g1" layout="horizontal" valign="middle" halign="start" rendered="true">
  <af:spacer width="15" id="pt_s1"/>
  <af:image id="pt_i1" source="/images/logo.png" inlineStyle="height:70px; width:70px;"/>
  <af:outputText value="My First Application" id="pt_ot1" inlineStyle="font-size:x-large; color:White;" noWrap="true"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

I am using JDeveloper 12c

**--- UPDATE ---**

I've tried following. But it gives slight different behaviour than expected.

```
<af:panelStretchLayout id="pt_psl2" startWidth="33%" endWidth="33%">
    <f:facet name="center">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl1" inlineStyle="min-width:33%;" halign="center" valign="middle">
            <af:outputText value="test application" id="pt_ot1" inlineStyle="font-size:x-large; color:White;" noWrap="true"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="start">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl3" inlineStyle="min-width:33%;">
            <af:spacer width="15" id="pt_s1"/>
            <af:image id="pt_i1" source="/images/test_logo.png" inlineStyle="height:70px; width:70px;"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="end">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl2" inlineStyle="min-width:33%;" halign="end" valign="middle">
            <af:image source="images/home.png" id="pt_i2"/>
            <af:link text="Home" id="pt_l5" inlineStyle="color:White;"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </f:facet>
</af:panelStretchLayout>
```

[image: Layout image. With current output and expected output.]

As we can see in output it starts content from the left side, while I want logo to start from left side, Application title in middle of the page and other links section from right side of the page.

How can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `af:panelStretchLayout` instead of `af:panelGroupLayout`. It has 5 *facets*. You can put your content in the "*center*" facets and either remove the others or put a spacer in them.

Comment: Hi Endrik, I've done the same. Actually I have to set the Header for the application. In which I've three sections Left part (i.e. Logo), Center part (i.e. Application name), and Right part (i.e. Other links). So I've used a panelStretchLayout and removed top and bottom facet, than set a width of start and end facet to 33%. So each parts are divided equally. Now in each faced I've taken af:PanelGroupLayout and put my all contents in each seprate PanelGroupLayout. Now problem is that all contents always start from  left side which is not desired.

Comment: I need to align Logo to left side, Application name in the center of the panel and other links should be right assigned.

Comment: Try to set the panelGroupLayout's "layout" property as "vertical" or "horizontal" (do not let it as default)

Comment: Endrik, this does the trick. Thanks. But now I face different issue. In right section I do have some links (say 3 link, including one menubar), This gots seprated in different lines. I want to render them in a single line. How can I achieve the same ?

Comment: Using horizontal layout on the panelGroup should be enough. Another way is putting all the links inside the menuBar

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks for your time :) Would be asking more questions in future :)

Comment: Can u please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310601/rowheaders-are-empty-in-crosstab-report-in-jasperreports

Answer (score 3):

Assuming on one of the later releases of ADF you should be looking into af:panelGridLayout to implement those type of UIs.

Comment: you mean using <af:panelGridLayout>, I can achieve the expected output for header part as image suggests ? I am using jDeveloper 12C

Comment: Yes you set the halign property of each af:gridCell to what you want it to be. start, middle, end. http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_gridCell.html

Comment: Wow, It's great. I wasn't aware of it. Thank you Shay :)

Comment: Sir, It would be very helpful if you can help with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234371/bounded-task-flow-not-working-for-a-page-with-dynamic-region